# How to create a database in sqlite3 from command line

Tags: linux, sqlite

From the command line `sqlite3` gives output:

```
SQLite version 3.11.0 2016-02-15 17:29:24
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite>
```

tried to quit after that using command
`sqlite> sqlite3&gt; .quit`

it does not quit but  gives output
`sqlite> sqlite3&gt; .quit
   ...>`

Then I come back to command prompt with ctrl+D

Then to create Database I entered command
`sqlite3 TheftSiren.db`

```
sqlite3 TheftSiren.db
SQLite version 3.11.0 2016-02-15 17:29:24
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite>
```

I used ctrl+D again to come to command prompt

To see if db i created I tried command

```
sqlite3&gt; .databases
[1] 2601
SQLite version 3.11.0 2016-02-15 17:29:24
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
gt: error: neither tool nor script specified; option -help lists possible tools

[1]+  Stopped                 sqlite3
.databases: command not found
```

it also failed

can someone tell what i the right way of handling these?

I also tried

```
'sqlite> sqlite3 TheftSiren.db
   ...> CREATE TABLE DB (
   ...> imei CHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   ...> mobile_num CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   ...> passwd     CHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
   ...> id         INT      NOT NULL
   ...> );
Error: near "sqlite3": syntax error'
```

and

```
'sqlite> sqlite TheftSiren.db
   ...> CREATE TABLE DB (
   ...> imei CHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   ...> mobile_num CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   ...> passwd     CHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
   ...> id         INT      NOT NULL
   ...> );
Error: near "sqlite": syntax error'
```

Comment: Don't spam tags. As asked, it is not realted to any of the two different programming languages C or C++.

Comment: Where did you get that `sqlite3&gt;` garbage from? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: https://iqbalnaved.wordpress.com/2014/07/10/how-to-install-sqlite-3-8-2-on-ubuntu-14-04-and-commands-for-creating-database-and-tables/ from this site

Comment: I am trying to create a databae and use it in c, linux program

Answer (score 2):

When you are in the normal command-line shell of your OS, you can run the `sqlite3` program to start the [SQLite command-line shell](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html). This is the only time you would ever enter "`sqlite3`".
When you are inside the SQLite command-line shell and want to re-start `sqlite3`, you have to quite it first with `.quit`.

The command-line shell prints "`sqlite>`" to show that you are in that shell, and that it expects SQL commands (or special [dot commands](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#special_commands_to_sqlite3_dot_commands_)). That web page shows "`sqlite>`" just because it is on the screen; never enter this by hand.

That web page did the HTML encoding wrong; `&quot;` is actually `"`, and `&gt;` is actually `>`.

Answer (score 0):

[CL.'s helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45399702/45375) explains the problems with your attempts well and provides helpful background information.

Based on the question's generic title, let me answer the question I *thought* was being asked when Google brought me here:

**How do I use the `sqlite3` *CLI* to *programmatically* create a database?**

`sqlite3` isn't just an *interactive* shell, it also accepts a series of statements *via stdin*.

The following examples create a `sample.db` database file with a sample table, `sample_table`, with two sample records:

- Note: The commands below use `bash` syntax, but work analogously in other shells.

```sh
# The commands to submit - note that each statement must be ";"-terminated.
cmds='
create table sample_table (Name string, Age int); 
insert into sample_table (Name, Age) values ("JDoe", 42), ("JRoe", 43);
'

# Pipe the commands to `sqlite3` while also passing the database file path.
echo "$cmds" | sqlite3 ./sample.db
```

Note:

- If `./samble.db` already exists, the commands will modify that existing database; if a table `sample_table` already exists, you'll get an error.
- The series of statements may also include:

  - `.<cmd>` commands such as `.headers on` (run `.help` from an interactive `sqlite3` session to see them all) - note that these must be *on their own line each*.
  - *Comment* lines, which must start with `#` *as the very first character*.

**To *query* the resulting table programmatically via the CLI:**

Note:

- This example uses a here-document to provide the stdin input to `sqlite3`, but you could use the same pipeline-based approach shown above.
- Note the need to put the `.headers on` command (which turns on including column names in query results) on *its own line*.

```sh
sqlite3 ./sample.db <<'EOF'
.headers on
select * from sample_table;
EOF
```

The above yields:

```
Name|Age
JDoe|42
JRoe|43
```